# TCP client/server in c

Tags: c, sockets

I created a TCP client/server and was provided test script, however, beyond short messages, all tests are failing. Simply, the script send arbitrary messages that the client reads through redirection from a file to ther server. However with randomly created files by the script, it says that the messages on receving/sending side do not match. Any help will be appreciated, below is the client and server code.

```
// server.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define QUEUE_LENGTH 10
#define RECV_BUFFER_SIZE 2048

/* TODO: server()
 * Open socket and wait for client to connect
 * Print received message to stdout
 * Return 0 on success, non-zero on failure
*/
int server(char *server_port) {
    int sockfd, new_fd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;   // connector's address 
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    char buff[RECV_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int numBytes;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my ip address

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, server_port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
    
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, QUEUE_LENGTH) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    // printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while (1) {
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        if((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        if (!fork()) { // child process
            close(sockfd);    // child does not need the listener
            if ((numBytes = recv(new_fd, buff, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE -1, 0)) == -1) {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }

            buff[numBytes] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buff);

            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
 * main():
 * Parse command-line arguments and call server function
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *server_port;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./server-c [server port]\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  server_port = argv[1];
  return server(server_port);
}
```

```
// client.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SEND_BUFFER_SIZE 2048

/* TODO: client()
 * Open socket and send message from stdin.
 * Return 0 on success, non-zero on failure
*/
int client(char *server_ip, char *server_port)
{
    int sockfd;
    int status;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;

    char send_buff[SEND_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int numbytes;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    // getaddrinfo
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(server_ip, server_port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getadrrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }

    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                             p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    // reading from stdin into send_buff, then send
    if((numbytes = read(0, send_buff, SEND_BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
        if (send(sockfd, send_buff, numbytes, 0) == -1) {
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

/*
 * main()
 * Parse command-line arguments and call client function
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *server_ip;
    char *server_port;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./client-c [server IP] [server port] < [message]\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    server_ip = argv[1];
    server_port = argv[2];
    return client(server_ip, server_port);
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: After freeing you shouldn't use `p` any more, the pointer got invalidated! Rather check the socket instead.

Comment: Your stdin input `< [message]` goes where? How you expect this input to be sent?

Comment: There is nothing here that 'says that the messages on receving/sending side do not match.' If you are assuming that one send == one receive you are mistaken in your assumption.

Comment: so input is through a text file, for example ./client 127.0.0.1 55554 < file.txt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2048 bytes exceed in size the typical [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) (note that TCP is laid over IP, which itself is packet oriented), so data is likely sent via multiple packets. As you have only one single call to `recv` chances are that you fetch the contents of first packet from the receive buffer before the the TCP/IP stack could place the contents of the follow up packets there.

Rather have multiple reads in a loop and exit the loop on receiving 0 bytes (remote socket closed):

```
while((numBytes = recv(new_fd, buff, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE -1, 0)) > 0)
{
    buff[numBytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buff);
}

if(numBytes < 0)
{
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'TCP packet'. There are TCP segments, which can be 2^32-1 bytes long, and there are IP packets, which ditto. Possibly you are referring to the MTU, which is typically but not always < 1500 bytes?

Comment: There is no such thing as an IP datagram either. See above. Datagram is a UDP entity, which has nothing to do with the question. Nor actually do (i) segment (ii) packet or (iii) MTU. The only thing that matters is the amount of data in the socket receive buffer when `recv()` returns.

Comment: @user207421 [@*%#$+!] – first being sloppy, then inattendent :( And I haven't even had some wine yet (or should I do so for better answers???) – thanks for the hints.

Comment: Whatever it takes, mate, I've had my wine ;-) But packets still have nothing to do with it. It's a byte-stream protocol, nothing else.

Comment: Sure it is – but `read` fetches those bytes that are available when calling. Why shouldn't that occur right in between two packets of the *underlying* protocol arriving? `recv` pretty sure is notified to wake up on first chunk of data arriving as the stack cannot know if there are further packets following to continue the stream.

Comment: It *can,* and most probably will, but there is nothing that says it *must*, which is the implication of your answer and your comment.

Comment: @user207421 `likely` and `chances are` not explicit enough?

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks, I guess you are right, I needed to have a loop, tests are now succeeding, However, I found it better to use fread/fwrite